# trying to get youtube videos to play in an iOS app but none of the rtsp links are working

Tags: ios, youtube-api

So I want to have a thumbnail of the video (that part works) and when the user clicks it, it plays the video full screen. I'm trying to put it into an MPMoviePlayerViewController. But I've tried both the h263 and the mpeg4 rtsp links and they fail (which actually crashes the app). But I've tried them in quicktime on my mac also, and they fail to load.

What's the secret?

Here is some example data:

```
"from_name": "epicmealtime",
"from_id": "epicmealtime",
"from_image_url": "https://i2.ytimg.com/i/Yjk_zY-iYR8YNfJmuzd70A/1.jpg?v=50cba2b0",
"message": "Bacon Beer Can Chicken - Epic Meal Time",
"create_time": 1364281243.0,
"post_id": "7DycWLAAEwY",
"post_type": "YouTube",
"description": "We like our chicks when they're drunk! NEW episodes of EpicMealTime every Tuesday, NEW episodes of Handle It every Saturday!!! Watch Episode 1 of Handle It! ...",
"video_thumbnail_url": "http://i.ytimg.com/vi/7DycWLAAEwY/default.jpg",
"rating": 4.8826127,
"h263_video_url": "rtsp://v7.cache5.c.youtube.com/CkULENy73wIaPAkGEwCwWJw87BMYDSANFEgGUgZ2aWRlb3NyIQGy7tHqcQHgzgWNsIjcB4KCDvPB7EI6RNWvHdRsUJxg5gw=/0/0/0/video.3gp",
"mpeg4_video_url": "rtsp://v7.cache5.c.youtube.com/CkULENy73wIaPAkGEwCwWJw87BMYESARFEgGUgZ2aWRlb3NyIQGy7tHqcQHgzgWNsIjcB4KCDvPB7EI6RNWvHdRsUJxg5gw=/0/0/0/video.3gp"
```

Thanks so much!

Comment: What API request did you use to get this data? What crash are you seeing?

Comment: I'm just getting unknown error when I try to load the video. I got the data from a search using the .net library which gets serialized objects.

Comment: The .net library? On iOS? Are you using MonoTouch or something? And what do you mean by “unknown error”? What's the exact text of the error?

Comment: I use a .net service that we made in house to pull this data from youtube. So I call the service from my iOS app, and I get this data. That part is correct. But when I try to play either of the links for the h263_video_url or the mpeg4_video_url it causes an error. The exact text is "unknown error". When trying on quicktime, it tries to load the file and then fails. I've made it so it doesn't crash anymore, because I listen for the error, but yeah, it is just sending back "unknown error"

Comment: What is sending you “unknown error”? The .net service, or some iOS API? If it's the latter, what specifically is returning the error?

Comment: From MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification I get MPMovieFinishReasonPlaybackError of Error Domain=MediaPlayerErrorDomain Code=-1 "unknown error" UserInfo=0x1dd3bc10 {NSLocalizedDescription=unknown error}

Comment: Hm. You mention that you're retrieving this data from your .NET service, not from YouTube. What happens if you try to watch a movie that you have just added on the back end?

Comment: Sorry, not sure is this is exactly what you mean, but if I load it with http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=post_id then open it up in a webview, it works but I see the whole youtube page. If I open it in the movieplayerviewcontroller, I gives an error, though thise time the error is "Operation Stopped".

Thanks so much for all your help btw.

Comment: I'm assuming that the data you keep in the .net service came from YouTube in some way. If you retrieve all of that anew for some video, store it in the .net service, and then retrieve it from the service in the app while it is still fresh, then what happens?

Comment: I decided to just play it using the web link and strip out the site. Thanks for your help with trying to fix the issue.